# How to run and stop a subserver node.js with spawn?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to start/stop a second app with node.js

I have the following 2 nodejs applications in a directory:

```
--app.js
 |
 -app2.js
```

Inside app.js

```
serverProcess = spawn('node', ['app2.js']);
process.stdin.pipe(serverProcess.stdin);

serverProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(`child stdout:\n${data}`);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('kill');
    serverProcess.stdin.pause();
    serverProcess.kill();
}, 5000);
```

Inside app2.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

What I would like to do is run app.js which runs app2.js for 5 seconds, logs the output to stdout, so I can see it, then terminate the process.

Currently, `app2.js` is killed, but `app.js` continues running and it is not terminating.

How would I correct my code so that `app.js` terminates as soon as `app2.js` is killed?

Comment: You shown code does not spawn the process for me. The correct usage of `spawn` would be `spawn('node', ['app2.js'])`. And if I replace `spawn('node app2.js')` with `spawn('node', ['app2.js'])` then both the spwan and the kill works.

Comment: thanks for the spot, I've up dated the code

Comment: What node version do you use and on which os did you test that? Because I can't reproduce the problem anywhere.  Or do you mean that the `app.js` process is not terminated?

Comment: Yes, app.js should finish and kill app2.js

Comment: `app2.js` **is** killed when I test it, but `app.js` is continue running. So is your problem that `app2.js` is not killed, or that `app.js` continues running after `app2.js` is killed?

Comment: app.js should stop if app2.js has?

Comment: Is that a question, or is that what you expect? The expected (and current) behaviour of your code is, that `app2.js` is killed, and `app.js` continues running until it receives some input through, `stdin`. Anyhow, I ask again:  Is your problem that `app2.js` is not killed, or your problem that `app.js` continues running after `app2.js` is killed?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was trying to make app.js run app2.js for 5 seconds. Then terminate app2.js, then terminate itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app.js` won't exit when `app2.js` killed because it will listen for input of the `stdio` stream due to the line:

```
process.stdin.pipe(serverProcess.stdin);
```

You either have to write `process.stdin.pause()` (not **`serverProcess`**) after your `console.log('kill')`.

Or remove the `process.stdin.pipe(serverProcess.stdin)` completely as you do not use the input you get via `stdin`.